# convert analog read to range to time

Tags: time, arduino

I'm trying to blink a led with analog sensor between 8 and 40 times a minutes

I have try this code but I realize that I had to convert the valorSensor to time.  How is the way to do it?

```
int led = 13;
int pinAnalogo = A0;
int analogo;
int valorSensor;

void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  analogo = analogRead(pinAnalogo);
  valorSensor = map(analogo, 0, 1023, 4, 80);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   
  delay(valorSensor);                       
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    
  delay(valorSensor);                      

}
```

Comment: You should create a function to describe the relationship between the value read and the value in time. You can try a simple linear function if you will. The first question is, what is the maximum value the `analogo` can output, and that will correspond to the 40 times/minute blink. Any range in between, you can get from the form `y = ax + c`.

Comment: One problem is in your map function.  You say you want to blink 4 times per second, but then you set the delay to 4.  In order to blink 4 times per second you would need a 125ms delay.   You're not telling it how many times to blink per second, you have to tell it how long to wait.  It's easy math.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not so much the code but biology. To see a blinking (and not just a flicker you will need times from 250ms and up) 24 frames/sec are perceived as motion so to get a "blink" you might start with 4 frames/sec (=250ms)
So my proposal is a blink without delay as function and a tuning parameter (blinkSpeedMultiplyer) for testing

```
 /* Blink without Delay as function
    Turns on and off a light emitting diode (LED) connected to a digital pin,
  without using the delay() function. This means that other code can run at the
  same time without being interrupted by the LED code.*/

// constants won't change. Used here to set a pin number:
const int blinkSpeedMultiplyer = 50; // very low
const int ledPin = 13;
const int pinAnalogo = A0;
// Variables will change:
// Generally, you should use "unsigned long" for variables that hold time
// The value will quickly become too large for an int to store
unsigned long startTime = millis();        // will store last time LED was updated
unsigned long blinkTime;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)
int analogo;
int valorSensor;
int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  analogo = analogRead(pinAnalogo);
  valorSensor = map(analogo, 0, 1023, 4, 80);
  blinkLed(valorSensor); // call the function
}

// Function to blink without blocking delay
void blinkLed(int inValue) {
  blinkTime = blinkSpeedMultiplyer * inValue;
  if (millis() - startTime >= blinkTime) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED
    startTime = millis();

    // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
    if (ledState == LOW) {
      ledState = HIGH;
    } else {
      ledState = LOW;
    }

    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  }
}
```